# Prisma schema one-to-many relations from multiple tables to one

Tags: prisma

I want to acomplish such schema, where user could have some images and recipes could have some images.

I came up with solution, but it throws this error for author and recipe rows in image model. My solution is to use type column as diferentiator between `Recipe` and `User` types.

> Error parsing attribute "@relation": The given constraint name `images_parentId_fkey` has to be unique in the following namespace: on model `Image` for primary key, indexes, unique constraints and foreign keys. Please provide a different name using the `map` argument.

My solution:

```
model User {
id          String       @id @unique @default(dbgenerated("gen_random_uuid()")) @db.Uuid
images      Image[]      @relation("UserImages")
Recipe      Recipe[]     @relation("RecipeAuthor")

@@map("users")
}

model Recipe {
id       String       @id @unique @default(dbgenerated("gen_random_uuid()")) @db.Uuid
authorId String       @db.Uuid
author   User         @relation("RecipeAuthor", fields: [authorId], references: [id])
images   Image[]      @relation("RecipeImages")

@@map("recipes")
}

model Image {
id         String     @id @unique @default(dbgenerated("gen_random_uuid()")) @db.Uuid
type       String
parentId   String     @db.Uuid
author     User       @relation("UserImages", fields: [parentId], references: [id])
recipe     Recipe     @relation("RecipeImages", fields: [parentId], references: [id])

@@map("images")
}
```

Only other solution I came up with is to create multiple tables for images, something like `user_images` and `recipe_images`, but i dont really like that and I might need even more tables like this in future, so I would rather find better way. Thanks in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `parentId` for both in `UserImages` and `ReceipeImages` relation. You can separate them out and have something like `parentUserId` and `parentReceipeId`.

The following solution could potentially work:

```
model User {
  id     String   @id @unique @default(dbgenerated("gen_random_uuid()")) @db.Uuid
  images Image[]  @relation("UserImages")
  Recipe Recipe[] @relation("RecipeAuthor")

  @@map("users")
}

model Recipe {
  id       String  @id @unique @default(dbgenerated("gen_random_uuid()")) @db.Uuid
  authorId String  @db.Uuid
  author   User    @relation("RecipeAuthor", fields: [authorId], references: [id])
  images   Image[] @relation("RecipeImages")

  @@map("recipes")
}

model Image {
  id              String  @id @unique @default(dbgenerated("gen_random_uuid()")) @db.Uuid
  type            String
  parentUserId    String?  @db.Uuid
  parentReceipeId String?  @db.Uuid
  author          User?   @relation("UserImages", fields: [parentUserId], references: [id])
  recipe          Recipe? @relation("RecipeImages", fields: [parentReceipeId], references: [id])

  @@map("images")
}
```

Comment: Nice solution, but I intend to have multiple tables which can have images, like users, recipes, ingredients, products and more and with this solution, I would have to have images table with a lot of columns (one for each related table), instead just two (type, and parentId). It is best solutions so far, but isnt there option to use type column, like I would do, if I didnt use prisma?

Comment: @Hovadko did you end up producing a solution?